# Jenkins parallel failed when function from imported class with map is triggered

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Jenkins parallel failed when function from imported class with map is triggered:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected a closure or failFast but found dev=automation_dev
```

Pipeline:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
@Library('SharedLibraries@master') _

def lib = new com.jenkins.dir()

pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label "master"
        }
    }
    parameters {
        string(defaultValue: "automation", description: '', name: 'createdir')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Create dir') {
            steps {
                script {
                    parallel lib.parallelCreateDir(createdir, this)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            script {
                deleteDir()
                cleanWs()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In src/com/jenkins/dir.groovy

```
package com.jenkins

class dir {
    // need to create constructor to use below variables or methods
    public dir() {
    }
    // variable for the environments
    def profiles = ["dev", "stg", "prod"]
    // variables converted to map
    def parallelCreateDir(String createdir, caller) {
         profiles.collectEntries { it ->
            caller.stage("Generate: ${it}") {
                caller.echo "${createdir}_${it}"
            }
            ["${it}": "${createdir}_${it}"]
        }
    }
}
```

In general method is working because print directories, but till the end failed:

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Create dir)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Generate: dev)
[Pipeline] echo
automation_dev
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Generate: stg)
[Pipeline] echo
automation_stg
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Generate: prod)
[Pipeline] echo
automation_prod
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] parallel
[Pipeline] // parallel
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected a closure or failFast but found dev=automation_dev
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.steps.ParallelStep$DescriptorImpl.newInstance(ParallelStep.java:278)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:266)
```

Comment: your `parallelCreateDir` function returns map of strings `["${it}": "${createdir}_${it}"]`, but parallel expects map of string-closure(stage)

Answer (score 0):

After answer from @daggett here is the solution which come up:

Pipeline:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
@Library('SharedLibraries@master') _

def profiles = ["dev", "stg", "prod"]
def lib = new com.jenkins.dir()

pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label "master"
        }
    }
    parameters {
        string(defaultValue: "automation", description: '', name: 'createdir')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Create dir') {
            steps {
                script {
                    parallel lib.parallelCreateDir(createdir, this, profiles)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            script {
                deleteDir()
                cleanWs()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

src/com/jenkins/dir.groovy:

```
package com.jenkins

class dir implements Serializable {
    // need to create constructor to use below variables or methods
    public dir() {
    }
    // variables converted to map
    def parallelCreateDir(createdir, caller, List<String> pProfiles) {
        pProfiles.collectEntries { it ->
            ["${it}": generateMap(createdir, caller, it)]
        }
    }

    def generateMap(String pCreateDir, caller, String profile) {
        return { it ->
            caller.stage("Generate: ${profile}") {
                caller.sh "cp -a ${pCreateDir} ${pCreateDir}_${profile}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```